# Events Fire Twice in jQueryMobile Application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with a **Phonegap** and **jQM** Application. In that, an event fires twice on Android devices.

To remove the flickering effects I set page transition to **'none'**.
When I click on the menu button it navigates to page 2. Also, another event fires at the same time on that page.

What is the solution?

Comment: If you can provide us with your code we can't help you. Your problem can happen in several different occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below code snippet in the head section of your web page in style tags.This may help.

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the above css code is for avoiding flickering effects, but not for avoiding triggering of events twice

Answer (score 1):

To resolve triggering of events twice, place pageinit function code in head section of your html page as

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
..your pageinit function code
</script>
</head>
```

**(or)**

Use jquery `on()` instead of jQuery `live()` method.