# Click event is not working smoothly in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on the jquery mobile app and i use many pages for it.I move to next page and come back to some page then click is not working perfectly as first time i go to the same page click event working smoothly .so please help me.

Comment: Can you attach any code ?

Comment: $.mobile.changePage("#"+page, "pop", false, true); where page is name of the page.

Comment: If the click event were not working smoothly in Jquery, then it'd be a major bug in the framework. It seems more likely that it has to do with how you use it so we'll need to see more code.

Comment: What do you mean by "click event is not working smoothly"? Are you talking about click event not working or transitions looking bad?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if this works.May be this is happening due to rough page transitions. Try turning off all the page transitions of jquery mobile.As it is not very smooth with page transition.
Add this attribute to your anchor tags where you need to navigate. `page-transition="none"`

Also try the `backface-visibility:none;` in css.as given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536973/events-fire-twice-in-jquerymobile-application/16537664#16537664)

**Update:**
Disabling the ajax may help.
Add `data-ajax="false"` to your the `<div>` of page.

Comment: i am not using anchor tag for this i am using image and on this call onclick .

Comment: @
NJInamdar now its working on browser fine but on ipad its not working smoothly.

Comment: Have updated the answer.We need to explore your code to track down the exact issue with ipad.

Comment: the problem  have been solved using this code                       var ua = navigator.userAgent,
 event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click"; on ipad